Proving a polynomial is positive on a subset
For positive parameters $a,b,c,d$ define
$$S_1=(x+1)(a+b)$$
$$S_2=(x+1)(c+d)$$
I want to show that for $x \geq 0$ we have
\begin{align*}
 &S_2\bigg[(a(S_2-c)+db)(x a+(x+1)b)-bS_1d\bigg]+[a(S_2-c)+bd][S_2a-S_1S_2+S_1d] \geq 0
\end{align*}
given that
\begin{align*}
    x \leq \frac{ad-bc}{(a+b)(c+d)}, \quad ad-bc \geq 0
\end{align*}
Coding this for different ranges of the parameter I think this is true. Also the given condition is essential as there are counterexamples otherwise. I don't see how we can use the condition. Any help will be appreciated. Also if someone could find a counterexample(which I don't believe exists).

It is possible to show that your expression equals
$$d(a + b)(x + 1)\big((a-b)(c+d)x + ad-bc\big).$$
The factors $d$, $a+b$, and $x+1$ are all positive, since $a,b,c,d>0$ and $x\geq 0$. So, this expression is nonnegative for $x\geq 0$ if and only if
$$(a-b)(c+d)x+(ad-bc)\geq 0.$$
Since this is linear in $x$, it is nonnegative for all $x\in \left[0,\frac{ad-bc}{(a+b)(c+d)}\right]$ if and only if it is nonnegative at the endpoints. If this interval is to be nonempty, we must have $ad-bc\geq 0$, so this expression is nonnegative at $0$. At $\frac{ad-bc}{(a+b)(c+d)}$, the expression equals
$$\frac{ad-bc}{(a+b)(c+d)}(a-b)(c+d)+(ad-bc)=\frac{2a(ad-bc)}{a+b}\geq0.$$
So, the expression is always nonnegative for $0\leq x\leq \frac{ad-bc}{(a+b)(c+d)}$.
